# Deserialization Gson X Android

Tags: java, android, json

Não estou conseguindo passar o valor da string JSON para uma entidade (OBJETO).

Já consegui receber o JSON, e código 200 de sucesso.
Mas não consigo colocar esse valor no objeto (Deserialization).

```
if (response.statusCode == ConversorConstantsAPI.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS) {
            // Deserialization
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            DolarDia dolarDia = gson.fromJson(response.json, DolarDia.class);

            //sponse.setResult(new Gson().fromJson(response.json, DolarDia.class));

            String line = "";

            result.setResult(dolarDia);
```

Classe DolarDia

```
public class DolarDia {
    public String mContext;
    public DolarDiaValores dolarDiaValores;
}
```

Classe Valores Dolar

```
public class DolarDia {
    public String mContext;
    public DolarDiaValores dolarDiaValores;
}
```

Valor recebido:

```
response.json {"@odata.context":"https://was-p.bcnet.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata$metadata#_CotacaoDolarDia(cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao)","value":[{"cotacaoCompra":3.96440,"cotacaoVenda":3.96500,"dataHoraCotacao":"2019-05-02 13:10:38.779"}]}



response = {APIResponse@4408} 
 json = "{"@odata.context":"https://was-p.bcnet.bcb.gov.br/olinda/servico/PTAX/versao/v1/odata$metadata#_CotacaoDolarDia(cotacaoCompra,cotacaoVenda,dataHoraCotacao)","value":[{"cotacaoCompra":3.96440,"cotacaoVenda":3.96500,"dataHoraCotacao":"2019-05-02 13:10:38.779"}]}"
 statusCode = 200
 shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4312} 
 shadow$_monitor_ = -1901606490
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma mudança nas classes, acredito que começando por ai vai da certo

public class DolarDia {
        public String mContext;
        public List values;

}

public class DolarDiaValores {
    public float cotacaoCompra = 0;
    public float cotacaoVenda = 0;
    public String dataHoraCotacao = "data";

}

chamada do metodo
if (response.statusCode == ConversorConstantsAPI.STATUS_CODE.SUCCESS) {

```
            // Deserialization
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            DolarDia dolarDia = gson.fromJson(response.json, DolarDia.class);

            String line = "";

            result.setResult(dolarDia);
```